# Database Design for efficency

Tags: mysql

I'm building a small plugin in PHP and mysql, that will basically take many different actions (around 50) and store them in a database.  It will keep all the records for each of the 50 actions users perform, and the number of users could reach 50,000. So you can see there will be alot of entries stored in a single table.

Here is the Table:

```
-- Table
CREATE TABLE `[db_prefix]entries` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lang_key` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `params` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `type` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `view`  enum('true','false') collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default 'true',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Basically, an entire month of actions for a user will be loaded at at time for a single user.

Is there some way to create indexes in the create table statement?  I would likely index user_id and content_id

Thanks for your help

Comment: I suggest you read up on WHERE CLAUSES in select statements, and DATABASE INDEXES before completing your design

Comment: As suggested by @MarkBaker best to familiarise yourself with indexes etc, however capacity-wise that volume of data is not a problem for MySQL to handle as long as you have sensible indexes and queries.  The question is very vague so would suggest further consideration of what you are aiming for / clarification.

Comment: I updated the question with some more details.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Table
CREATE TABLE `[db_prefix]entries` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lang_key` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `params` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `type` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `view`  enum('true','false') collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default 'true',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `content_id` (`content_id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```